# how to access the json array in following format

Tags: android, arrays, json

i am trying to access the json data from server, I have accessed the first json array from file but I don't know how to access the another json array from that file. Any help would be appreciated. 
my url of json file is as follows

```
String jsonurl" = "http:// 66.7.207.5 /homebites/list_business_category.php?b_id=18";"
```

I have accessed json array "business" as follows,
    json_object_main = json_parser.getJSONObjectFromUrl(jsonurl
                                                        + res_id);
    Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", json_object_main + "");

```
if (json_object_main != null) {

try {

  JSONArray json_array_header = json_object_main
                                .getJSONArray("business");

  JSONArray j=json_object_main.getJSONArray("business_cat");

  //JSONArray json_cat=json_parser.getJsonArayFromUrl(jsonurl+res_id);
```

now I want to access json array "business_cat"

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
JSONArray j=json_object_main.getJSONArray("business_cat");          
for(int i=0; i < j.length(); i++)
{

   JSONObject jsonAttribs = j.getJSONObject(i);  
   //do whatever you want to do with the elements
   jsonAttribs.getString("SOME_KEY"); 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But while using this code i got Exception. org.json.JSONException: Value null at business_cat of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: The error says its a JSON object, not an array. In that case I need to see your JSON data.

Comment: @HiteshKamani please put some valid data in your json response instead of null. check again!